# Emacs v24.4 hangs on start up

Tags: osx

Has anyone found or has an idea why Emacs hangs on start up. I see a lot of posts about this issue but it seems that this is not fixed yet. It also appears that this only happens to older machines, and specifically when many apps are running in the same time.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in the upcoming Emacs 25 release.

It was caused by input events arriving before the initialization had finished. The problem was worse when the machine was under heavy load, like when Emacs was launched after a reboot.

**Update:**

This has been reported a number of times by users, including:

- [#18849: 24.4; Crash on Mac OS X 10.10 when automatically launched at startup](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18849)
- [#19879: 24.4; Hang on startup on OS X (GUI only)](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19879)
- [#20228: 24.4; Hanging process on OS X Yosemite when launching Cocoa built Emacs.app](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20228)

Comment: What issue? "*Emacs hangs on start up*"? And only on older machines? And only when many apps are running? How does that description specify a particular issue? The question is hopelessly vague, so I don't see how this could answer it. If it does, great, but I don't see that. IMO, the question should be closed as unclear or too broad.

Comment: This is a genuine problem. When I start Emacs 24, it hangs about 1 out of ten times. When using an instrumented Emacs, I noticed that there was a racing problem between the init code and arriving events.

Comment: Great. Hope that solves the OP problem described. Is there an Emacs bug # for this issue? (If so, it might be good to link to that bug thread.)

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was reported a number of times on OS X. However I found it independently, which is why I didn't refer to a bug number in the commit. I'll try to find dig through the bug database and see if I can find them.